# PostgreSql. Выбрать только одинаковые значения

Tags: postgresql, sql

Необходимо из таблицы выбрать значения, истинные для всех значений подзапроса. Поясню: имеется некая таблица, использующаяся для связи "многие-к-многим", например так:

ent-id | prop-id
  1  | 1
   1   |   5
   1   |   7
   2   |   1
   2   |   5
   2   |   2
   3   |   7
   3   |   2

если подзапрос возвращает ent-id 1 и 3, должно быть отобрано значение prop-id 7, если  ent-id 1 и 2, prop-id 1 и 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Операция называется реляционным делением.
Некоторые методы реализации можно найти [здесь](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_relational_division.html).